# Find a limit: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[m]{1 +\alpha x}\sqrt[n]{1 +\beta x} - 1}{x}; m, n \in \mathbb{Z}; \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sqrt[m]{1 +\alpha x}-1}{\alpha x} = \frac{1}{m}; \frac{ \sqrt[n]{1 +\beta x}-1}{\beta x} = \frac{1}{n}$$
What do I need to do to get to this?

Comment: Use l'Hospital  $ $

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch How can I solve it without l'hopital?

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative then (with $f(x):=\sqrt[m]{1+\alpha x}-1$) if you want to "go around" l'Hospital

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Is it possible to convert the original limit to get the expression that I wrote below?

Comment: @gimusi has provided a full answer below

Answer (score 2):

We have that by [**Binomial approximation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation)

- $\sqrt[m]{1 +\alpha x}=1 +\frac{\alpha x}m+o(x)$
- $\sqrt[n]{1 +\beta x}=1 +\frac{\beta x}n+o(x)$

therefore

$$\frac{\sqrt[m]{1 +\alpha x}\sqrt[n]{1 +\beta x} - 1}{x}=\frac{\frac{\alpha x}m+\frac{\beta x}n+o(x)}{x}$$